# How to send dynamic multipart data request

Tags: karate

[image]Below lists shows different dynamic multipart requests

**Request_1**

```
Given url appServer
And path '/integration/rest/application/WmSOAPProvider' 
* configure charset = null
Given multipart file properties = { read: 'classpath:ic/feature/soap/TestData/soapInputWSDLData.json', filename: 'blob', contentType: 'application/json' }
Given multipart file wsdlFiles = { read: '#(wsdlFilesPath)', filename: '#(wsdlFilename1)', contentType: 'application/xml' }
And header Content-Type = 'multipart/form-data'
When method post
```

**Request_2**

```
Given url appServer
And path '/integration/rest/application/WmSOAPProvider' 
* configure charset = null
Given multipart file properties = { read: 'classpath:ic/feature/soap/TestData/soapInputWSDLData.json', filename: 'blob', contentType: 'application/json' }
Given multipart file wsdlFiles = { read: '#(wsdlFilesPath)', filename: '#(wsdlFilename1)', contentType: 'application/xml' }
Given multipart file wsdlFiles = { read: '#(wsdlFilesPath)', filename: '#(wsdlFilename2)', contentType: 'application/xml' }
Given multipart file wsdlFiles = { read: '#(wsdlFilesPath)', filename: '#(wsdlFilename3)', contentType: 'application/xml' }
And header Content-Type = 'multipart/form-data'
When method post
```

**Request_3**

```
Given url appServer
And path '/integration/rest/application/WmSOAPProvider' 
* configure charset = null
Given multipart file properties = { read: 'classpath:ic/feature/soap/TestData/soapInputWSDLData.json', filename: 'blob', contentType: 'application/json' }
Given multipart file wsdlFiles = { read: '#(wsdlFilesPath)', filename: '#(wsdlFilename1)', contentType: 'application/xml' }
Given multipart file wsdlFiles = { read: '#(wsdlFilesPath)', filename: '#(wsdlFilename2)', contentType: 'application/xml' }
And header Content-Type = 'multipart/form-data'
When method post
```

**Request_4**

```
Given url appServer
And path '/integration/rest/application/WmSOAPProvider' 
* configure charset = null
Given multipart file properties = { read: 'classpath:ic/feature/soap/TestData/soapInputWSDLData.json', filename: 'blob', contentType: 'application/json' }
Given multipart file wsdlFiles = { read: '#(wsdlFilesPath)', filename: '#(wsdlFilename1)', contentType: 'application/xml' }
Given multipart file wsdlFiles = { read: '#(wsdlFilesPath)', filename: '#(wsdlFilename2)', contentType: 'application/xml' }
Given multipart file wsdlFiles = { read: '#(wsdlFilesPath)', filename: '#(wsdlFilename3)', contentType: 'application/xml' }
Given multipart file wsdlFiles = { read: '#(wsdlFilesPath)', filename: '#(wsdlFilename4)', contentType: 'application/xml' }
Given multipart file wsdlFiles = { read: '#(wsdlFilesPath)', filename: '#(wsdlFilename5)', contentType: 'application/xml' }
Given multipart file wsdlFiles = { read: '#(wsdlFilesPath)', filename: '#(wsdlFilename6)', contentType: 'application/xml' }
Given multipart file wsdlFiles = { read: '#(wsdlFilesPath)', filename: '#(wsdlFilename7)', contentType: 'application/xml' }
Given multipart file wsdlFiles = { read: '#(wsdlFilesPath)', filename: '#(wsdlFilename8)', contentType: 'application/xml' }
And header Content-Type = 'multipart/form-data'
When method post
```

`request1`,`request2`,`request3`,`request4` all are having dynamic multipart wsdl file input.
Using Karate how to make it generic so that any number of multipat wsdlfile it should work

Answer (score 1):

See the [`multipart files`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#multipart-files) keyword, that allows you to handle when the number of files is dynamic.

Comment: * set json.myFile1 = { read: 'classpath:ic/feature/soap/TestData/googleWeather.wsdl', filename: 'googleWeather.wsdl', contentType: 'application/xml' }
* set json.myFile2 = { read: 'classpath:ic/feature/soap/TestData/googleWeather.wsdl', filename: 'googleWeather.wsdl', contentType: 'application/xml' } and I am sending 'json' as parameter for multipart files. But the json content is going with key name.

Comment: Below response shows the content of json. How to avoid sending key names for multi part json files    Response: {
  "myFile1": {
    "read": "classpath:ic/feature/soap/TestData/googleWeather.wsdl",
    "filename": "googleWeather.wsdl",
    "contentType": "application/xml"
  },
  "myFile2": {
    "read": "classpath:ic/feature/soap/TestData/googleWeather.wsdl",
    "filename": "googleWeather.wsdl",
    "contentType": "application/xml"
  }
}

Comment: Can you please give an example of multi part files where the number of files are dynamic and key names may vary for each request

Comment: @Anupama if this doesn't help, hope someone else can help: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/upload/upload-multiple-files.feature

Comment: Hi Peter,  Thanks for response. With your solution request is going as inputJson={myFile1={read=classpath:ic/feature/soap/TestData/googleWeather.wsdl, filename=googleWeather.wsdl, contentType=application/xml}, myFile2={read=classpath:ic/feature/soap/TestData/googleWeather.wsdl, filename=googleWeather.wsdl, contentType=application/xml}}}.  But our API expects each file with 'Given multipart file wsdlFiles ='. I will see if someone else can help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: @Anupama can provide a `curl` or payload expected from your server.

Comment: Hi Babu, Thank you for response.  I have attached the request payload for your reference.

Comment: In the request payload 'properties' multipart u can ignore. it is optional. But 'wsdlfiles' is mandatory